# Send MMS automatically in android

Tags: android

I am beginer in android. I use this code to automatically send MMS

```
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      i.putExtra("address","1234567890");
      i.putExtra("sms_body","hai");
      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,path);
      i.setType("image/jpg");
      startActivity(i);
```

but it shows application chooser and when we select messaging application ,the image is loaded with message, but it can't send automatically. we need user interaction for this. I would need to automatically choose message app and send MMS automatically without user interaction. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SmsManager API

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);

Built-in SMS application

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: it just shows the interface... i want it send automatically without user action